# Factory girl and rspec unit testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I am using factory_girl_rails and rspec and run into trouble,
raises the folloing error

```
   1) WebsiteLink when link is external
         Failure/Error: website_link.external should be false

           expected #<FalseClass:0> => false
                got #<WebsiteLink:100584240> => #<WebsiteLink id: nil, website_id: nil, link: nil, external: nil, checked: nil, click_count: nil, transition_count: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, link_description: nil>

           Compared using equal?, which compares object identity,
           but expected and actual are not the same object. Use
           `expect(actual).to eq(expected)` if you don't care about
           object identity in this example.
```

It is my code in spec.rb file

```
it "when link is external" do
    website = FactoryGirl.create(:website,site_address: "www.socpost.ru")
    website_link = FactoryGirl.create(:website_link, link: "www.google.com", website: website)
    website_link.external should be true
  end
```

The factory_girl factories

```
FactoryGirl.define do
 factory :website do
    sequence(:site_name){ |i| "Facebook#{i}" }
    sequence(:site_address){ |i| "www.facebook_#{i}.com" }
    sequence(:website_key){ |i| (1234567 + i).to_s }
  end
  factory :website_link do
    sequence(:link){ |i| "www.facebook.com/test_#{i}" }
    external false
    checked false
    click_count 1
    transition_count 1
    link_description "Hello"
    website
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to use the `dot`.

```
it "when link is external" do
  website = FactoryGirl.create(:website,site_address: "www.socpost.ru")
  website_link = FactoryGirl.create(:website_link, link: "www.google.com", website: website)
  website_link.external.should be true (note the dot between external and should)
end
```

Give it a try.

Answer (score 5):

Since I think it's helpful to understand *why* you received the error you received, here's an explanation:

- You're statement had four expressions separated by spaces: `website_link.external`, `should`, `be` and `false`
- Ruby evaluates these from right to left
- `false` is trivial
- `be` is interpreted as a method call with `false` as an argument
- `should` is interpreted as a method with the result of `be` as an argument.
- `should` is interpreted relative to `subject`, since the method wasn't sent to a specific object
- Given the error you received, `subject` was either explicitly set to be `WebsiteLink` or that was the argument to `describe` for a parent of the example and thus the implicit `subject`
- `website_link.external` never got evaluated because the error occurred prior to that point